# useNuxtApp nuxt instance is unavailable during static site build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am using the `nuxtApp` to build a plugin for mixPanel to make its instance available for the entire application. When I run the `npm run generate` command to prerender the routes I get the **302 error** for the pages that use that plugin. **This error states the nuxt instance is unavailable**
 
  I also checked the **.output/public dir** and all the other routes are present except for the routes that use the `useNuxtApp`.

Here is my plugin

```js
import mixpanel from "mixpanel-browser";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  mixpanel.init(config.mixPanelToken, { debug: true });

  nuxtApp.provide("mixpanel", mixpanel);
});
```

and here is how I am using it inside the component

```js
  const { $mixpanel } = useNuxtApp();
```

Is there any workaround for this problem because I need these pages to be pre-rendered for SEO?